# running commands in docker-compose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, sails.js, docker-compose

I am trying to run two docker containers on a VPS machine that has Ubuntu 15.10 and am using `docker-compose` for this. One container is a mongodb server and the other runs my web app written in node.js/sails.js.

I wrote the following in `docker-compose.yml` so that `docker-compose up` will run both containers. I am mounting the web app to the directory `/host` in the web app docker container and would like to do a port mapping `3050:1337` (host:docker). In order to run the web app, I used the `command` label and use bash to change directory and execute `sails lift` command, however, it does not work. I guess my following script is wrong:

```
MongoDB:
  image: mongo

MyAPI:
  image: sailsjs-microservice:dev
  volumes:
   - /root/Code/node/My-API:/host
  command: bash -c "cd /host && sails lift"
  ports:
   - "3050:1337"
```

I appreciate your help

Comment: Hmm I guessing you forgot to add a link to your db in your API section. The API service should be able to connect to that mongo instance right?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen the logs in your sailsjs-microservice container but I think you should add a link to your mongo container in your API container.

One way to do it's adding this to your compose file:

```
MyApi:
   links:
    - mongo:mongo
```

The first *mongo* is the name of the image you want to link, the second is an alias, could be db for example. Docker will export the container's IP address as a environment variables and also add a `/etc/hosts` entry for that so that you could reference it in your service`s code by connecting to mongo:27017 (where **mongo** is the alias defined in the compose file and 27017 is the default port).

Take a look on [link environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/link-env-deprecated/)

Answer (score 1):

```
MongoDB:
  image: mongo
  networks:
      - myApi-tier

MyAPI:
  image: sailsjs-microservice:dev
  volumes:
   - /root/Code/node/My-API:/host
  command: bash -c "cd /host && sails lift"
  networks:
      - myApi-tier

networks:
  myApi-tier:
```

You can try with the network, now inside your service to resolve mongodb you can use the standard port and like uri MongoDB.